# SQL Server 2012 create xml with a variable number of attributes

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table like this

```
;with cte_list(ID, PROPERTY_NAME, PROPERTY_VALUE) as 
(
    select '100', 'ABC', 12 union all
    select '100', 'AD',  32 union all
    select '100', 'AQ',   9 union all
    select '200', 'AES',  1 union all
    select '200', 'FS',   5
)
```

and I would like to have this result

```
ID      XML
---     -----------------------------------
100,    <codes ABC="12" AD="32" AQ="9"/>
200,    <codes AES="1" FS="5" />
```

Is this possible?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

**One approach**

```
;with
cte_list(ID, PROPERTY_NAME, PROPERTY_VALUE)
as (
select '100', 'ABC', 12 union all
select '100', 'AD',  32 union all
select '100', 'AQ',   9 union all
select '200', 'AES',  1 union all
select '200', 'FS',   5
)
Select A.ID
      ,XML = cast('<codes '+Stuff((Select concat(' ',Property_Name,'="',Property_Value,'"') From cte_list Where ID=A.ID For XML Path ('')),1,1,'') + ' />' as xml)
 From (Select Distinct ID from cte_list) A
```

**Returns**

```
ID  XML
100 <codes ABC="12" AD="32" AQ="9" />
200 <codes AES="1" FS="5" />
```

A word of caution:  The `property_name` should be XML safe strings (no spaces, etc.)

Comment: One of the rare moments where the creation on string level is an option :-D

Answer (score 1):

Another option with a known set of attributes would be a combination of `PIVOT` and the fact, that XML will omit any `NULL` values.

```
;with cte_list(ID, PROPERTY_NAME, PROPERTY_VALUE) as 
(
    select '100', 'ABC', 12 union all
    select '100', 'AD',  32 union all
    select '100', 'AQ',   9 union all
    select '200', 'AES',  1 union all
    select '200', 'FS',   5
)
SELECT l1.ID 
     ,(
        SELECT
           MAX(CASE WHEN PROPERTY_NAME = 'ABC' THEN PROPERTY_VALUE END) AS [@ABC]
          ,MAX(CASE WHEN PROPERTY_NAME = 'AD' THEN PROPERTY_VALUE END) AS [@AD]
          ,MAX(CASE WHEN PROPERTY_NAME = 'AQ' THEN PROPERTY_VALUE END) AS [@AQ]
          ,MAX(CASE WHEN PROPERTY_NAME = 'AES' THEN PROPERTY_VALUE END) AS [@AES]
          ,MAX(CASE WHEN PROPERTY_NAME = 'FS' THEN PROPERTY_VALUE END) AS [@FS]
         FOR XML PATH('code'),TYPE
      ) AS YourCodeXML
FROM cte_list AS l1
GROUP BY l1.ID
```

The result

```
ID  YourCodeXML
100 <code ABC="12" AD="32" AQ="9" />
200 <code AES="1" FS="5" />
```

The advantage: You do not need to work on string level
The draw back: If there is a new attribute, you'd have to add it to the list.

Another chance was dynamically created SQL...